# Creating simple filter ribbon with mplfinance / matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[Filter ribbon green/red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJGqn.png)

Hello guys!

Do you have any idea how to create a bottom ribbon like this (red/green) one with mplfinance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [finplot](https://pypi.org/project/finplot/), this is fairly easy:

```
import finplot as fplt
import yfinance

df = yfinance.download('GOOG')
ax = fplt.create_plot('Alphabet 1D')
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']], ax=ax)

# create a ribbon around MA200/50
df['ma200'] = df.Close.rolling(200).mean()
df['ma50'] = df.Close.rolling(50).mean()
df['one'] = 1
fplt.volume_ocv(df[['ma200','ma50','one']], candle_width=1, ax=ax.overlay(scale=0.1))

fplt.show()
```

[image: finplot]

*Disclaimer:* I am the author of finplot.